# Material UI autocomplete not being recognized

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using React. This is the version of the `material-ui` and I do not update want to update to the `material-ui` v5 since most of what I'm working on is written in v4

[image]

It says that Autocomplete' is not exported from '@material-ui/core'.
This is how I imported it

```js
import {
  Grid,
  Card,
  makeStyles,
  CardHeader,
  CardContent,
  TextField, 
  Autcomplete
} from "@material-ui/core";
```

This is also the sample Autocomplete that I plan to use:

```
<Autocomplete
  disablePortal
  id="combo-box-demo"
  options={top100Films}
  sx={{ width: 300 }}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autocomplete is not part of `@material-ui/core` in Mui v4.

Import it from the lab

```js
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
```